# MSBuildShellExtension alternative?

Tags: msbuild, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

Any alternatives out there to [MSBuildShellExtension](http://www.codeplex.com/msbuildshellex) for running msbuild targets from the Explorer context menu? I'm looking for an alternative that is a bit more dynamic than MSBuildShellExtension -- e.g., instead of requiring manual configuration of build targets, reading available targets from the selected project file and listing these in a submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [MSBuild Sidekick](http://attrice.info/msbuild/). Other than that there are not many offerings out there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [MSBuildShellExtension](http://www.codeplex.com/msbuildshellex) project has been revived, and the 2.0 release will dynamically pull targets from the selected project file. Not perfect yet (I'd like to see the ability to filter out certain targets, and to selectively pull targets from imported file), but it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try out my new project,

http://msbuildlaunchpad.codeplex.com/releases/view/45368

It is quite easy to use.
[MSBuild Launch Pad http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=msbuildlaunchpad&DownloadId=122261](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=msbuildlaunchpad&DownloadId=122261)